# How to use function as a variable?

Tags: python

So I was trying to do a small Hangman program as practice, but I came across a problem: If I define a function (with `return` statement), then use that as an argument for another function, I get a `TypeError`.

```
def two_player_hangman():
    player_1_input = input(print("What is your word? "))
    player_1_list = list(player_1_input)
    return player_1_list


def blank_space_creator(in_list1):
    word_list = []
    for a in range(0, len(in_list1)):
        word_list.append("-")
    return word_list

a = blank_space_creator(two_player_hangman)
print(a)
```

If I were to input, say, the word `'hi'`, I should get `['-', '-']`.
But instead, it raises: `TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable`.

Comment: `in_list1 = two_player_hangman() a = blank_space_creator(in_list1)` ? Essentially assign the output of function to a variable, and  pass that to the other function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace by this :

```
a = blank_space_creator(two_player_hangman())
```

To take into argument the output of `two_player_hangman`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding parentheses to your 'two_player_hangman' function while calling it :

`a = blank_space_creator(two_player_hangman())
print(a)`

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes in your code as follows:

```
def two_player_hangman():
    player_1_input = input("What is your word? ") # you don't need to provide print method inside of the input method
    return player_1_input


def blank_space_creator(in_list1):
    word_list = []
    for a in in_list1: # converting a string into a list and then counting the number of elements in the list is not efficient here, instead you can directly iterate over a string
        word_list.append("-")
    return word_list

a = blank_space_creator(two_player_hangman()) # you have to call the method
print(a)
```